# Kivy official Pong tutorial - usage of Vector (kivy.vector)

Tags: python, kivy

I've been following official Kivy PongApp tutorial ([link](http://kivy.org/docs/tutorials/pong.html) - whole program code at the bottom of site) and I've faced a problem I can't really understand.

I've defined the move function to change the position of the ball by a velocity vector on each frame. The code:

```
def move(self):
    self.pos = Vector(*self.velocity) + self.pos
```

However, when I've written the code like this:

```
def move(self):
    self.pos = self.pos + Vector(*self.velocity)
```

It results in an error:
ValueError: PongBall.pos value length is immutable

Why, shouldn't it be the same?

Comment: To clarify, you're saying that if you write the code the first way, it works, but throws the exception if you write it the second way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is just because the Vector type overrides addition to do vector addition, and in the first case its `__add__` is called which automatically treats self.pos (a list) as another vector.

In the second case, the `__add__` of self.pos is called, which doesn't know about the Vector type and tries instead to do normal list addition which extends the length of the list. This fails with the error you see, since the `pos` must be a list of fixed length.

So overall (if I'm right), the problem is that `+` does different things depending on the types of its arguments. This usually isn't important, but happens to make a big difference here.

Answer (score 7):

`self.pos` is a [`kivy.properties.ObservableReferenceList`](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/properties.pyx#L1074).

When you attempt to set this property it checks to make sure that the new value is the same length as the old value.

From [`kivy.properties.ReferenceProperty`](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/properties.pyx#L1142):

```
cdef check(self, EventDispatcher obj, value):
  cdef PropertyStorage ps = obj.__storage[self._name]
  if len(value) != len(ps.properties):
    raise ValueError('%s.%s value length is immutable' % (
      obj.__class__.__name__, self.name))
```

In addition, [`kivy.properties.ObservableList`](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/properties.pyx#L545) subclasses `list`.

Unfortunately, so does [`kivy.vector.Vector`](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/vector.py#L88), and as anyone with Python experience can tell you, `list.__add__` concatenates its arguments.

What this means is that vector is added to `self.pos` by *extending* it, not by adding it elementwise, which then causes `self.pos` to complain because its length is changing.

It works the other way aronud because `Vector` [overloads `__add__`](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/vector.py#L88) to do element-wise addition.

Because python favors `__add__` over `__radd__`, the whole thing fails.